# Vector of pointers to base class containing base and derived class objects - accessing derived-class specific variables

Tags: c++, object, pointers, vector, polymorphism

I've been struggling with with this **C++** thing for a while. I've created base object class and derived object class and I'm trying to store references to both base and derived objects in a vector of base-class pointers (avoid object slicing).
With pointer, I am able to run virtual methods and I can confirm that pointer points to derived-class object, however I cannot get to derived class specific variables. Is there any way of doing it ?

**Base class object:**

```
class Base
{

public:

    Manager* manager;

    Base(){}
    Base(Manager* mManager){
        manager = mManager;
    }

    virtual void init(){}

    virtual void speak() {
        std::cout << "Base class is speaking!" << std::endl;
    }

};
```

**Derived class object:**

```
class Derived : public Base
{

public:

    Manager* manager;

    int DerviedVariable = 100;

    Derived(){}
    Derived(Manager* mManager){
        manager = mManager;
    }

    void speak() override {
        std::cout << "Derived class is speaking!" << std::endl;
    }

};
```

Those objects (Base na Derived) are created and stored using **Manager class** and array called **groupedEntities :**

```
constexpr std::size_t maxGroups = 32;
using Group = std::size_t;

class Manager
{
public:

    std::array<std::vector<Base*>, maxGroups> groupedEntities;

    void addToGroup(Base* mBase, Group mGroup)
    {
        groupedEntities[mGroup].emplace_back(mBase);
    }


    std::vector<Base*>& getGroup(Group mGroup)
    {
        return groupedEntities[mGroup];
    }

    template <typename T, typename... TArgs>
    T* addEnt(TArgs&&... mArgs)
    {
        T* e(new T(this));
        return e;
    }

};
```

I am create objects and try to reference them like that :

```
void main() {

    std:size_t groupBlob = 0u;

    Manager* manager = new Manager();
    Derived* blob1(manager->addEnt<Derived>());
    Derived* blob2(manager->addEnt<Derived>());


    manager->addToGroup(blob1, groupBlob);
    manager->addToGroup(blob2, groupBlob);


    auto& grouped(manager->getGroup(groupBlob));

    for (auto& e : grouped)
    {
        e->speak();
        std::cout << e.DerviedVariable ;

    }


}
```

Unfortunately, **e.DerviedVariable** is inaccessible, whereas **speak()** function says "Dervied class is speaking". Is there any way to access Derived-class variables with this architecture? Thanks

Comment: Unrelated: `main()` must be declared to return `int`.

Comment: Add a pure virtual function `virtual int getDerviedVariable() = 0;` to `Base` and implement it in `Derived`

Comment: If you think you need to get to derived-class-specific variables from a base class pointer, your design almost certainly needs work. Typically, either the base class should provide a virtual function for the job, or your pointers should be to the derived class, not the base. Think about what makes sense given what your classes are supposed to represent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You only need to cast the pointer. The simplest syntax is:

`((Derived*)e)->DerviedVariable`

which is equivalent (modulo casting away constness, if any) to C++ish

`static_cast<Derived*>(e)->DerviedVariable`

The word “static” here reminds that there is no runtime checking: the compiler trusts you that `e` indeed points to an instance of `Derived`. If it doesn’t, undefined behavior occurs. The safer alternative is `dynamic_cast`:

```
Derived *ee = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(e);
if (ee)
    x = ee->DerviedVariable;
```

It returns NULL if the object is not an instance of `Derived`. (Note that references can be casted as well, but as there is no NULL reference, `dynamic_cast` will throw instead if cast is not possible)

Nevertheless, using such casts is often considered a bad practice, for a reason. Virtual functions are preferable, mostly because using them don’t require you to even know the actual object type at the call point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dynamic_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) in such cases. The expression `dynamic_cast<Derived*>(e)` where `e` is of type `Base*` will evaluate to a `Derived*` if `e` does in fact point to an object of `Derived` type, otherwise it will evaluate to a null pointer.

```
if(Derived* d = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(e)) {
    std::cout << d->e.DerviedVariable;
}
```